# Problems with the click event in a TableLayout

Tags: android, android-tablelayout, tablerow

Good Morning everyone,

I'm facing yet another problem in my path of learning Android. I made a dynamic TableLayout with the content of an CSV file. I need that when I click/touch a row in the table, the color should change, and later with a click of a button get the content of the same line. Now I'm stucked with the first part and of course I have no clue about how to get the data of the row.

I declared the table inside a LinearLayout that is also inside of a ScrollView in my layout with the following properties:

```
    <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollMotors"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutMotors"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tableMotors"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:stretchColumns="*" >

        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

After in my java code, I declared the creation of the line:

```
        //Initialization of my table
    my_tableMotors = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableMotors);
    //This is an ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> that contains the lines of the CSV file,
    //I use this variable as a dynamic Matrix because my CSV file can change its dimensions.
    m = valuesFile.size(); 
    for (n = 0 ; n < m ; n++)
    {
        //Declaration and initialization of my rows
        final TableRow line = new TableRow(MotorActivity.this);
        //Setting the parameters of my row
        line.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        line.setFocusable(true);
        line.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        line.setClickable(true);
        //Initialization of my TextViews that are gonna be the content of each one of the rows in the dynamic TableLayout
        myCol1 = new TextView(MotorActivity.this);
        myCol2 = new TextView(MotorActivity.this);
        myCol3 = new TextView(MotorActivity.this);
        myCol4 = new TextView(MotorActivity.this);
        j = valuesFile.get(n).size();
        for (i = 0 ; i < j ; i++)
        {
            switch(i)
            {
            case 0: 
                if (n == 0)
                {
                    myCol1.setText("Line");
                }
                else
                {
                    myCol1.setText(valuesFile.get(n).get(i)); //Sets value for the column
                }
                line.addView(myCol1);
                break;
            case 1:
                myCol2.setText(valuesFile.get(n).get(i)); //Sets value for the column
                line.addView(myCol2);
                break;
            case 2:
                myCol3.setText(valuesFile.get(n).get(i)); //Sets value for the column
                line.addView(myCol3);
                break;
            case 3:
                myCol4.setText(valuesFile.get(n).get(i)); //I use this variable for some other purpose
                break;
            }
        }
        my_tableMotors.addView(line);
    }
    my_tableMotors.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {public void onClick(View v) {onClickedRow(); }});
}
```

From what I've seen and read here, the best is to use a setOnClickListener and that's what I did using a bit of two different answers that I found here:

```
    public void onClickedRow()
{
    m = my_tableMotors.getChildCount();
    for (n = 0 ; n < m ; n++)
    {
        if (my_tableMotors.getChildAt(n).hasFocus())
        {
            my_tableMotors.setBackgroundColor(myColor);
        }
    }
}
```

Now I can't get any focus at the tableLayout at all, so please if you see something wrong in my code or if you know how to help me with this I would appreciate it a lot!!!!

Many thanks in advance :).

**EDIT 1**

I found the way to get the focus. I changed the method not to the whole TableLayout but only to the TableRow, so ended up as this:

****Before****

```
        my_tableMotors = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableMotors);
    m = valuesFile.size(); 
    for (n = 0 ; n < m ; n++)
    {
        //Declaration and initialization of my rows
        final TableRow line = new TableRow(MotorActivity.this);
        /*Other declarations*/
        j = valuesFile.get(n).size();
        for (i = 0 ; i < j ; i++)
        {
            /*Code*/
        }
        my_tableMotors.addView(line);
    }
    my_tableMotors.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {public void onClick(View v) {onClickedRow(); }});
}
```

****After****

```
    my_tableMotors = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableMotors);
m = valuesFile.size();
for (n = 0 ; n < m ; n++)
{
    //Declaration and initialization of my rows
        final TableRow line = new TableRow(MotorActivity.this);
    /*Other declarations*/
    j = valuesFile.get(n).size();
    for (i = 0 ; i < j ; i++)
    {
        /*Code*/
    }
    line.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {public void onClick(View v) {onClickedRow(); }});
    my_tableMotors.addView(line);
}
```

I also made the change on how to set the color of the line:

****Before****

```
my_tableMotors.setBackgroundColor(myColor);
```

****After****

```
my_tableMotors.getChildAt(n).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.myColor);
```

Now I'm busy finding out how to get the data from the TableRow. As soon as I get that solve or an answer from you I think I have my problem solved!!!

**EDIT 2**

With the help of @Luksprog I could find an answer to my problem of retrieving the content!!! I did used the next code using his solution:

```
    public void onClickedRow()
{
    TableRow clickedRow = new TableRow(MotorActivity.this);
    m = my_tableMotors.getChildCount();
    for (n = 1 ; n < m ; n++)
    {
        if (my_tableMotors.getChildAt(n).isFocused())
        {
            my_tableMotors.getChildAt(n).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.highlightTableRow);
            clickedRow = (TableRow) my_tableMotors.getChildAt(n);
            j = clickedRow.getChildCount();
            for (i = 0; i < j ; i++)
            {
                switch(i)
                {
                case 0:
                    myField1 = (TextView) clickedRow.getChildAt(i);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    myField2 = (TextView) clickedRow.getChildAt(i);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    myField3 = (TextView) clickedRow.getChildAt(i);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't set the `OnClickListener` on the `TableLayout` instead set it to each `TableRow` that you create in that for loop:

```
for (n = 0 ; n < m ; n++) {
    //Declaration and initialization of my rows
    final TableRow line = new TableRow(MotorActivity.this);
    line.setOnClickListener(mListener);
    line.setId(1000 + n);
    // ...
```

where `mListener` is:

```
OnClickListener mListener = new OnClickListener() {

     public void onClick(View v) {
         // v is the TableRow that was clicked
         v.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
         // mClickedPosition is a int field representing the clicked row(to know the position later)
         // if you allow more than one row to be clicked at one time, use a list of ints
         // or something like this
         mClickedPosition = v.getId() - 1000; 
     }
}
```

To later retrieve the content of the row you would use the `mClickedPosition` variable:

```
TableRow clickedRow = (TableRow) my_tableMotors.getChildAt(mClickedPosition);
// having the child TableRow that was clicked you could extract any data you want from it
// of course you could simply use the mClickedPosition to extract the data from whatever data structure you have(I'm looking at valuesFile)
```

Comment: Yes, I just saw it, I made an edit in my post. Thanks a lot for your answer!!!! I'm gonna try the last code you posted to retrieve the content to see if it works :).

Comment: thanks a lot with your post!!!! You can see how I used it on my 2nd edit of my thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the following code according to your requirement.
Here Your go:-

```
public void createTable() {
        TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableMotors);
        table.removeAllViewsInLayout();

        List<String> namesList = new ArrayList<String>();
        namesList.add("name");
        namesList.add("name2");
        namesList.add("name3");

        // display dynamic table rows
        for (int counter = 0; counter < namesList.size(); counter++) {
            TableRow row = new TableRow(this);

            // add the index view to the row
            TextView index = new TextView(this);
            index.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            index.setId(100);
            index.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            String indexString = String.valueOf(counter + 1);
            index.setText(indexString);

            // textview to display names
            final TextView nameView = new TextView(this);
            nameView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            nameView.setId(0);
            nameView.setText(namesList.get(counter));
            nameView.setTextColor(Color.RED);

            RelativeLayout relativeRowContent = new RelativeLayout(this);

            // set the layout params for the control to be added
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            rlp.setMargins(10, 0, 0, 0);
            rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
            relativeRowContent.addView(index, rlp);

            // add the divider after index
            final TextView indexDivider = new TextView(this);
            indexDivider.setWidth(1);
            indexDivider.setId(101);
            indexDivider.setHeight(80);
            indexDivider.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);

            // display the index
            rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            rlp.setMargins(80, 0, 0, 0);
            rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
            relativeRowContent.addView(indexDivider, rlp);

            // set the layout params for the control to be added
            rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            rlp.setMargins(10, 0, 0, 0);
            rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, indexDivider.getId());
            relativeRowContent.addView(nameView, rlp);

            // finally add the relative row content layout in the table row.
            row.addView(relativeRowContent);
            /* row.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.row_border_light); */

            // add the row to the table.
            table.addView(row, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this,
                            "" + nameView.getText().toString(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    // or do something more use full here.

                }
            });

        }
    }
```